# check countdowntime to running or not?

Tags: java, android, timer, countdowntimer

I have timer that I can set my timer to ring.
and also I have a pause button to stop the timer.
when you inter to app for the first time cause there is no timer to pause.
when you click to pause button I Got the error.
 here is my timer:

```
long result = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

                        timer = new CountDownTimer(result, 1000) {


                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                time.setText(("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000));
                                //create HashMap<Integer,String> textMap at the constructer of the adapter
                                //now fill this info int'o it
                                textMap.put(new Integer(position), "seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                                //notify about the data change
                                notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }

                            public void onFinish() {

                                time.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                //create HashMap<Integer,String> textMap at the constructer of the adapter
                                //now fill this info into it

                                textMap.put(new Integer(position),null);
                                //notify about the data change
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "finish", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                if (rowView != lastview || mediaPlayer == null) {
                                    play(position);
                                    if (lastview != null)
                                        lastview = rowView;
                                } else {
                                    play.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_btn_play_unselected);
                                    mediaPlayer.release();
                                    lastview = null;
                                }


                            }

                        }.start();
                        deleteDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

and here is my pause button:

```
      stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                time.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //create HashMap<Integer,String> textMap at the constructer of the adapter
                //now fill this info into it
              int  position=0;
                textMap.put(new Integer(position),null);
                //notify about the data change
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                    timer.cancel();


            }            });
```

how to ckeck my time is running or not?
I got nullpointexecption when click on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if it is running:

```
if(timer != null){
    //Here the timer will be running
}
```

But then, when you cancel you have to do the following:

```
timer.cancel();
timer = null;
```

So if the timer is not null, means is it running. If it is null means user has cancelled it.